# "Too few positionals" in macro definition

Tags: macros, raku

I'm trying to create some examples of using (experimental) macros this way:

```perl6
use experimental :macros;
macro cards_vars() { 
  (<hearts clubs diamonds spades> X~ 1..10).map: { "my \$$^x = False;" }  
};
cards_vars(); 
say $hearts1;
```

This creates and runs the macro, and then checks if one of the variable defined exists. But I get this error:

```perl6
Too few positionals passed; expected 3 arguments but got 2
```

I don't even know where that error comes from. I think it's in cards_vars(), but I have no idea if that's the case or not. Declaring the macro without the parentheses yields the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** To be clear, macros are not just experimental but very rudimentary and buggy. For a little more about this, see [Moritz's answer to another macros question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53902789/1077672).

---

Let's start with a golf of your code:

```
use experimental :macros;
macro foo { 42 }
foo
```

This yields the same *compile-time* error:

```
Too few positionals passed; expected 3 arguments but got 2
```

You get this error if you return anything other than an [`AST`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/AST) object from a macro.<sup>1</sup> Which is reasonable given that this is the entire point of the `macro` construct. The error message is less than awesome -- but then again macros are an experimental feature.

---

So you need to return an AST. Here's one way:

```
use experimental :macros;
macro foo { AST.new }
foo
```

This yields the *run-time* error:

```
Useless use of constant value foo in sink context (line 3)
```

This shows that the macro has done its job. The compiler has completed compilation and proceeded to run-time.

---

Explicitly returning `AST` objects is the wrong way to proceed. The first reason is given on the `AST` doc page:

> There is no API defined for ASTs yet. Hopefully that will emerge as part of [the work on macros](https://github.com/masak/007).

The second reason is that there's a higher level construct for constructing `AST` objects, namely the `quasi { ... }` construct<sup>3</sup> mentioned on the doc page and by Scimon:

```
use experimental :macros;
macro foo { quasi { 42 } }
say foo; # 42
```

The `quasi` block tells the compiler to compile the enclosed statements into AST form.

Note that the result isn't an AST corresponding to a block. In the above it's an AST object corresponding to `42`.

---

So, finally, back to what you were trying to do.

Simplifying:

```
use experimental :macros;
macro foo { quasi { my $bar } }
foo;
say $bar
```

yields:

```
Error while compiling ... Variable '$bar' is not declared
```

Whereas:

```
use experimental :macros;
macro foo { quasi { class bar {} } }
foo;
say bar; # (bar)
```

So, bottom line, lexical declarations currently fail to stick.

The experiment hasn't gotten that far.

Carl Mäsak, the creator of the experimental macros in Rakudo, is continuing the experiment at [007](https://github.com/masak/007). If you leave an issue at its GH repo Carl will answer.

---

<sup>1</sup> When the compiler encounters a call to a routine that it knows is a macro<sup>2</sup> it replaces the macro call with its result. In more detail the compiler:

- Compiles all the macro's arguments into AST form;
- Calls the macro (at compile-time) passing it the arguments in their AST form;
- Runs the macro routine which is expected to return an AST object (er, ["ASTish"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53904138/1077672));
- Splices the resulting AST(ish) object into the overall AST being constructed.

If you don't return an AST(ish) object the last step goes wrong with the error message in your title.

<sup>2</sup> Currently, if you put the macro definition *after* the call then the compiler doesn't realize it's a macro and treats it as an ordinary routine:

```
use experimental :macros;
say foo; # 42
macro foo { 42 }
say bar; # AST.new
macro bar { quasi { 42 } }
say bar; # 42
```

It would presumably be better if this caused a compile-time error.

<sup>3</sup> Carl, the macros champion, likes the word `quasi`. It draws from lisp heritage which draws from mathematics heritage. Imo it is a "too cute" choice that's a less than awesome fit for P6. My rationale is that Perl philosophy suggests choice of keywords with familiar meaning to newbies. The word "quasi" has a well known normal English connotation of meaning "sort of, but not really". That's not at all helpful. (I have suggested `toAST` to Carl but he prefers `quasi`.)

Answer (score 5):

So a bit of poking about and I found this old halloween article : https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2012/12/23/day-23-macros/

Which gives some pointer. You need to use `quasi` to highlight the code you're going to output. But getting it to create a variable? Not sure. I'm still setting if it's possible.